# For Anime Modellers: How to paint Anime hair with many hair objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, texture-painting, hair

[image: 1]

Hi, this is a hair model I've been given to try and paint in an "anime style".

Are there tips or tutorials you guys can give on how I can approach to painting this?

[image: 2]

My aim is to make the hair look close to this -- or something simpler.

Comment: does this help? [link](https://blenderartists.org/t/anime-style-specular-highlight/1166732)

Comment: thanks, I'll test it out. Does this mean I don't have to hand paint the hair and use a shader instead?

Comment: yeah i think its possible just with shaders,there is a cool node shader to color . i think you can use that as well

Comment: can you tell me what shader node is that?

Comment: idk how add pictures to comment see if answer help

Answer (score 1):

[image: shader]

using reflection as color from glossy shader and maybe vertex coordinates to adjust that effect and also using diffuse and emission for anime style
try different types on math node that i set to square root maybe absolute , you will get different results
its just an idea maybe you can work with this to get what you want

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and copy this. Altough I can't seem to read what node is the one on the top most part. It's a bit pixelated.

Comment: its
Fresnel node

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! :)